# How should I store multiple session pairs of a user in Redis?

Tags: rest, authentication, session, redis

I'll store the session id and user id pair in the Redis. Yeah, It seems easy to achieve, but I am new into the Redis. How should I store these pairs if I would like to invalidate the multiple sessions of a user.

You may think like the below; a user can login with multiple devices. such as; a browser, a mobile browser.

I have to invalidate/remove all of these session ids of the user when they change the password.

Thanks for helps.